# iOS inconsistencies (modal vs push)

Tags: navigation, ios

The iOS settings app has some inconsistencies I want to bring up to discuss the reasoning for their choices.

1. `Settings > General > Language & Region > Region` uses a modal with a filter input.
2. `Settings > General > Language & Region > Calendar` uses a push.
3. `Settings > General > Date & Time > Time Zone` uses a push with a search input.

I can understand why #2 uses a push because it sort of acts like radio buttons except you go to a different page. But #1 and #3 confuse me. Even though they use different type of search/filter, why do they navigate differently?